# How to import row wise data in csv file in R

Tags: r

I have values corresponding to sales in my text file like
10,34,56,78,89,...etc
Now I would like to import these values and assign them to sales variable in R .

I'm trying with **sales<- read.table('C:..../sale.txt',separator=",")** for which I'm getting 
  Vector 1   Vector 2...
1  10  34  56  78  89 
which does not help me out. Could you please help me in getting these values into a single variable?

Thank you in advance.

Regards
Ravi

Comment: If there's a header you need `header = TRUE` in `read.table`, as FALSE is the default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scan` :

```
## replace text = by your file=filename
scan(text='10,34,56,78,89',sep=',')
Read 5 items
[1] 10 34 56 78 89
```